# Unable to run a simple "Hello World!" project using NetBeans IDE 8.1, Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, spring, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I am a beginner in Spring. Trying to run a simple "Hello World!" project using NetBeans IDE 8.1, Glassfish 4.1

Here is my code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tryspring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tryspring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.jsp">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

index.jsp

```
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.</p>
    <p><i>To display a different welcome page for this project, modify</i>
        <tt>index.jsp</tt> <i>, or create your own welcome page then change
            the redirection in</i> <tt>redirect.jsp</tt> <i>to point to the new
            welcome page and also update the welcome-file setting in</i>
        <tt>web.xml</tt>.</p>
</body>
```

But when I am running the project no page is being displayed.

```
Error: "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found"
```

Can any one please help on this?

Also this code is generated by NetBeans IDE.
I have just modified the dispatcher modifier from `*.htm` to `*.jsp`. Is it causing the problem?

Comment: Any errors in the server logs? (which you will find in a specific tab in the Netbeans output view)

Comment: @Gimby no such errors instead there is no error.

Comment: ... is there any output in the server logs that indicates the server started successfully? I would just post the log output here as well. Also, which URL is in the browser window when you run the application?

Answer (score -1):

Your code dosen´t really matter. It´s the redirection as mentioned in the error message that is not present. Notice that redirect is only browser side, if you want to do it on server side you need to use forward.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("your file.js");
rd.forward(request, response);
```